# Timeout error awaiting promise in Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am testing a Serverless lambda function and get a timeout error which I believe is due to an await promise().

```
module.exports.create = async (event) => {
  const provider = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider
  ....//stuff here where I split auth token to get ids...
  const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    apiVersion: "2016-04-18"
});
const getUserParams = {
  UserPoolId: userPoolId,
  Username: userPoolUserId
};
const data =JSON.parse(event.body)
const getUser = await cognito.adminGetUser(getUserParams).promise()
  const params = {
    Item:{
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      email: getUser, //!timeout issue probably here!
      content: data
    }
  };
  try {
    const { Listing } = await connectToDatabase()
    const listing = await Listing.create({userId: params.Item.userId, email: params.Item.email
```

In researching a solution, I have come across people splitting up the lambda into two functions so that they collectively pass the timeout. I do not know how to reference a lambda within a lambda, nor am I sure this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You change the timeout for lambda function
default timeout for lambda function is 3 sec you can override in below the function code basic settings

Comment: I am using AWS API Gateway which has a timeout of 30 seconds- this is where the timeout limit is coming from. I have read that this value is not adjustable

Answer (score 0):

For anyone googling this: turns out adminGetUser needs a NAT Gateway configured in order for it to be able to retrieve data from Cognito. I was getting a timeout error because it was not executing, period. Read here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/.